# Dynamic split form layout in C#

Tags: c#, forms, layout, controls

I'm trying to create a dynamically splitted form in C# (Windows Forms) for using it as a video stream monitoring application. Just imagine it as a default look of a surveillance application or the usually standard virtual desktop view in linux distributions running x.

```
_________________________
|           |           |
|   scr01   |   scr02   |
|           |           |
|-----------+-----------|
|           |           |
|   scr04   |   scr04   |
|___________|___________|
```

Now, it's easy to accomplish the view above using "TableLayoutPanel". Defining 2 rows, 2 columns with height and width 25% each.
But I'd like to set my view dynamically by defining ROWS and COLUMNS as numbers. Using the TableLayoutPanel, I'm able to define the rows and columns needed, yes, but  whatever I define, the layout is messed up.

Because: There is no such thing like a column or a row like in a real table. TableLayoutPanel just defines some integers that the form has to draw as cells with properties defined in TableLayoutPanelRow/Column Styles. Also no option for a working "Autosize" property.

What's the best way to accomplish something like this? TableLayoutPanel is a horrible form entity, is there another control I could use? Or do I have to calculate everything, drawning controls at their position with every form resize etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fed up with the `TableLayoutPanel`, you could use [`Panel`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) and [`Splitters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitter.aspx). This way you should be able to specify the exact location of each component with a good deal of accuracy.

You could also use split containers, but you then have less freedon in terms of specifying the splitter width etc.

I hope this helps.